# Delaunay triangulation doesn't work

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create a Delaunay triangulation of a set of 3692 points with QGIS 1.8.0. The resulting set of polygons appears unfinished, leaving a small part of the original map uncovered by triangles and a small set of points not used in any triangle. Is there a limit of the number of input points or is there some other constraint?

Best regards from France

Comment: Can you provide a link or graphic showing the results you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GRASS GIS for this - the most easy way is through the Sextante plugin, no GRASS skills are required. It shall deliver a complete Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: Good idea, this also helped with my problematic dataset.